# member function pointer to member function

Tags: c++, class

There is a lot of talk of pointers to member functions but I'm having trouble grasping the issue with the hidden const state of member functions. Can anyone give me a simpler answer what I'm doing wrong here?

```
class Entity
{
public:
    Entity();
    void(Entity::*update_function)();
private:
    void update_mode_1() {
    }
};

Entity::Entity()
{
    update_function = update_mode_1;
    //error C3867: 'Entity::update_mode1': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
}

void test_init() {
    Entity obj;
    obj.update_function();
    //Error: Expression preceding parenthesis of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type
}
```

Comment: There is no 'issue with the hidden const state' here, and there are also two very explicit messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the solutions how to solve the errors, anyway, it seems has nothing to do with "hidden const state of member functions".

> error C3867: 'Entity::update_mode1': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

As the error message said, use `&` to create a pointer to member.

```
update_function = &Entity::update_mode_1;
```

> Error: Expression preceding parenthesis of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type

Use [pointer-to-member access operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_pointer-to-member_access_operators) (such as the operator `.*`) to call it.

```
(obj.*(obj.update_function))();
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/QLUV97495)